# How to create a dynamic model for days of week names in schedule?

Tags: python, django, django-models

For the gym schedule, I need to create a model with which I will get a list of seven days names. The list will be updated daily, so in the first place will always be the current day of the week. Every day the list will be shifted to one day, so, for example, in the cell in which the word “Wednesday” stands today, tomorrow the word “Thursday” will appear, the day after tomorrow - “Friday” and so on. The names of the days should then be retrieved into the view and passed to the template.

I tried to do it like this:

```
import calendar
import datetime
from datetime import *
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class DayOfWeekSchedule(models.Model):
    """General dynamic schedule for a week"""

    DOW_CHOICES = (
        (1, _("Monday")),
        (2, _("Tuesday")),
        (3, _("Wednesday")),
        (4, _("Thursday")),
        (5, _("Friday")),
        (6, _("Saturday")),
        (7, _("Sunday")),
    )
    day_of_week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=DOW_CHOICES, 
        verbose_name=_('Day of week')
        )

    def days_of_week(self):
        my_date = date.today()
        current_day_name = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]
        index1 = DOW_CHOICES.index(current_day_name) #from Monday=0 (i.e. Friday=4)
        list_daynames = list(DOW_CHOICES[index1:] + DOW_CHOICES)[:7] #list of names, current is first
        list_index = (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1) #to compensate systems difference
        list2 = list(list_index[index1:] + list_index)[:7]
        context_days = dict(zip(list_keys, list_daynames))
        return context_days
```

But

`DOW_CHOICES.index (current_day_name)`

and

`list_daynames = list (DOW_CHOICES [index1:] + DOW_CHOICES) [: 7]`

, as expected, do not work, because .index () is not applicable to tuples of this type.

And how to do it, I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're overthinking this. If I understand what you want correctly, you could just do something like this:

```
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta

 days = {
    '1': _('Monday'),
    '2': _('Tuesday'),
    '3': _('Wednesday'),
    '4': _('Thursday'),
    '5': _('Friday'),
    '6': _('Saturday'),
    '7': _('Sunday')
}

DOW_CHOICES = []

today = datetime.today()
for i in range(7):
    day_number = (today + timedelta(days=i)).isoweekday()
    day = days[str(day_number)]
    DOW_CHOICES.append((day_number, day))
```

This gets the today's date and creates a list of tuples with day number and day. The result will be:

```
[
    (3, 'Wednesday'), 
    (4, 'Thursday'), 
    (5, 'Friday'), 
    (6, 'Saturday'), 
    (7, 'Sunday'), 
    (1, 'Monday'), 
    (2, 'Tuesday')
]
```

Comment: wow! yes, i believed, i believed that it can be done so fine)) thanks!